# Powershell relative path to repo file

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-3.0

I am trying to refer relative path to file which is in the same repo as powershell script.

I have following dir structure.

```
repo/
 ├── files
 │   └── scripts.sh
 │   
 ├── powershell_scripts
      └── my_powershell.ps1
```

in `my_powershell.ps1` I want to refer `scripts.sh`. I tried to use `$PSScriptRoot` in the powershell script but it didn't work the way I want.

I want`my_powershell.ps1` to pickup `scripts.sh` with directory structure.

anyone knows how do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I see you have PSv2 listed as a tag. Are you actually going to be running this on version 2?

Comment: Running it on powershell-v3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in v3 or higher this is simple. If you want the path to the "Repo" folder you could simply refer to the parent of the current folder such as:

```
$Repo = Resolve-Path "$PSScriptRoot\.."
```

This will get you the folder object of Repo. From there you could get to your script folder.

Or to directly refer to the `scripts.sh` file you could do:

```
Resolve-Path "$PSScriptRoot\..\files\scripts.sh"
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt get this, can specify the full command I need to use to refer `scripts.sh` into `my_powershell.ps1`

Comment: I tried `$Repo = Resolve-Path "$PSScriptRoot\.."` then `Write-host $Repo` which printed `C:\`

Comment: Refer `scripts.sh` into `my_powershell.ps1` how? try `Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\..\files\scripts.sh"`